# Friend from Russia wants to visit Canada

Tags: visas, canada, russian-citizens

If a friend wants to visit Canada from Russia, would it increase the likelihood that my friend’s visitor visa application (by invitation) would be approved, if my friend first got a Schengen visa?

Comment: I don't know that just *getting* a Schengen visa would be all that much help. Getting and *using* (complying with all of the rules and returning home) would probably have a greater positive impact.

Comment: Being granted a visa to (and particularly traveling to and returning timely from) western affluent countries is a positive event on ones immigration history. Of course getting denied is also a possibility, and that is a negative.

Comment: If your friend has a job in Russia, probably he should not have problem. [Russia is much more expensive then Canada]. If she is a girl, check out Russia embassy website (of your country) and read about the girlfriend scam.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi "much more expensive"? How so? Even Moscow looks cheap (-30 to 40%) compared to Toronto and most of Russia is much poorer. Of course local purchasing power is similarly lower. It's definitely not a third world country, if that's your point.

Comment: Is getting a Schengen visa so much easier than getting a Canadian visa?  I wouldn't think so.  If your friend can get a Schengen visa without first having traveled to Canada, your friend can probably also get a Canadian visa without first having traveled to the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog Canadian visas are among the most difficult visas to get in western countries.

Comment: @phoog for Russian citizens getting Schengen is usually pretty easy. Citation: rejection rates per country.

Comment: @alamar Do you have a source for Canadian rejection rates? I couldn't find one. But even a higher rate does not imply that a given Russian person would be less likely to get a Canadian visa. The different rate could reflect a different applicant pool or, likely, the nature of the planned travel. There are probably 10 million Russians within driving distance of the Schengen area. Someone driving across the border for a shopping trip is much more likely to get a visa than someone flying in for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Travel history is what is considered in some visa applications, not merely issuance of a visa. If your Russian friend has never visited another country, with a visa or visa-free entry, then obtaining a Schengen visa may have little value.

An invitation to house and feed your friend could help; financial sponsorship, however, may not be favorable. The visa decision process takes into account many factors, and no one can predict the outcome.